# I'm getting Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ":"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const wordpressSiteUrl = 'http://projects.stagingsoftware.com/quacito_new/blog';
  this.setState(stats: { loading: true }, callback: () => {
  axios.get(url: `${wordpressSiteUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`)
 });
}
```

I want wordpress blog fetch in react js but I'm unable that

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it just like this. Just add curly brackets `{}` in setState and axios.

```js
componentDidMount() { 
    const wordpressSiteUrl = 'http://projects.stagingsoftware.com/quacito_new/blog'; 
    this.setState({stats: { loading: true }, callback: () => { axios.get(url=` ${ wordpressSiteUrl }/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`) }}); 
}
```